# HTACCESS 403 : How to block url with a specific character?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using WordPress and I have some duplicate URL by spammer

`https://www.example.com/caterory/article-name/` ==> OK

`https://www.example.com/caterory/article-name/?vn/2022-06-24fivhg585.html` ==> Wrong

I would like to block this kind of URL with string `?vn/`

I tried this but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot) [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^*vn/ [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^*vn/

RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `^` means start of subject, and `*` is the zero-or-more quantifier. The combination `^*` makes little sense.

Comment: There is no need to check the `User-Agent` header. In fact, you should not check the `User-Agent`. This still makes the erroneous URLs accessible to all other bots and users - why? If these URLs have already been indexed by Google then user's will still be able to follow them in the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you. Make sure to place it at the top or before your WP rewriterule block .

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot) [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^vn/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

If you want to test this rule yourself , just comment out or remove the condition line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot) [NC]` and visit any URL starting with the querystring `?vn` . You will get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to target googlebot and bingbot only here.